# HTML, CSS: scrollable table with fixed footer

Tags: html, css

I have a long table that I don't want to show in full length, because then the footer and other elements below it are only shown after scrolling down for long.

How can I assign Header, Footer and other elements and then let the table fill up the remaining height?

By now I'm using a flexbox to distribute the free space to the table wrapper, but the table content gets shown in full length and the footer is pushed down.

I also tried to nest an `overflow: auto;` into an `overflow: hidden;` but then it's not scrollable at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for footer try ==>  position:fixed;

Comment: Post your code that you have tried..

Comment: Please consider posting a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [w3schools - CSS Layout - The position Property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) guide?

Just use `footer{ position:fixed }` for your footer in your CSS along with other style codes.

> An element with `position: fixed;` is positioned relative to the
> viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the
> page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used
> to position the element. A fixed element does not leave a gap in the
> page where it would normally have been located.
> (As Mentioned in the w3schools).

Hope you will get your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the css specification for the footer element to `position: fixed;` If you want header to be fixed set the header css specification also to `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 1):

just use **position:fixed** in ur footer css...and if u want to have scroll then use css **overflow:scroll;** if u want hide ur scroller in the page then use **overflow:hidden;**